# Un-kosher pan in a kosher oven

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, appliances

If someone has a perfectly kosher oven which is designated only for dairy and parve meals. He accidentaly put there a non-kosher pan with some dairy food. What now, is his oven still kosher after that?

Comment: CYLOR,  may be that the oven is still Kosher but ask a rav who will ask a couple of questions about the case

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Can you [edit] your question to make it less personal? We [try to avoid practical halachic questions](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734). You might also want to see "[Why is it necessary to ask a rabbi?](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146)" for more info. We hope to see you around!

Comment: @Zarah Yehudit look please my edit, check  if you accept it.

Comment: Welcome Zarah! Consider reading this short [Beginners' Guide](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3887/8775) to the site.

Comment: @Zarah...great question, can you edit your question so we can know more about the case? When was the last time the oven was used before the non-kosher pan was put in? When was that pan last used for non-kosher? Was there any real non-kosher food in the pan now or was it clean? Was the dairy meal heated in the pan kosher? How hot was the oven when the non kosher pan was placed? What was now in the pan and with it in the oven if anything? Was the pan covered or open?

Comment: @DavidKenner Note that it is not our place to pasken Zarah Yehudit's shaila. That's what rabbis are for.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Yes true, but there is no other way to answer the question without knowing those things. The difference between psak and answer is essentially how it all will be phrased. The details will sound just like the details needed for a psak.

Comment: @DavidKenner if by "answer the question," you mean "analyze Zarah's [particular situation](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3760/closure-of-complex-scenario-questions) and advise her what to do," as this sort of probing seems to indicate, then that's just not our role, whether the advice uses the pronoun "you" or the pronoun "one."

Comment: @IsaacMoses No "advice" is implied. The question cannot be reasonably answered without the details. This seems no different than all the other such Halachic questions on the site. I suggest you easily review my long list of answers I already have given on this site and if you feel I am paskening for people and wish to critique my actions, my email is Davidariel25@gmail.com :)

Comment: @IsaacMoses One other benefit of my note is it will enable the OP to understand what they should know in order to form  a shaila for a Rav and understand what the shaila is and what the Rav means. We haven't even heard if the oven was on yet :)